# Laravel 7 with postgresql ltree does not work

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-7, ltree

I need to update my application from laravel 5 to laravel laravel 7
I'm using postgresql ltree on few column and this is my migration code

DB::statement("ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN mycolumn ltree");

that migration is running well on laravel 5, but on laravel 7 it giving error
(I run it on same machine, already installed ltree extension)

SQLSTATE[42704]: Undefined object: 7 ERROR:  type "ltree" does not exist at character 35

did anyone have solution for this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure ltree extension is enabled on the database?
try running this in your `psql`: `create extension ltree;`

Comment: yes, as i said i run it on same machine